Timeout when connect to ip in ingress network in docker swarm
I have run my service with docker swarm, I have two nodes, and I'v run the service with replicas=2.
Here is my docker compose
services:
  c2c-mplus-gateway-service:
    hostname: c2c-mplus-gateway-service
    image: c2c-mplus-gateway-service:1.0
    working_dir: /usr/src/myapp
    command: bash -c "nohup java -jar /usr/src/myapp/gateway-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    networks:
      - mplus-network
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Bangkok
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod, api-docs, no-liquibase
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 2.5G
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
networks:
  mplus-network:
    external: true

I run the service with is command:
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack_c2c-mplus-gateway --detach=true

These are networks when I run docker network ls:
NETWORK ID     NAME                                        DRIVER    SCOPE
21f0a74c5b20   bridge                                      bridge    local
652d6041a5a5   docker-registry_default                     bridge    local
2be7df7c024d   docker_gwbridge                             bridge    local
d3444c9e3eec   host                                        host      local
ia5xtksz2i2e   ingress                                     overlay   swarm
9crf4h745f63   mplus-network                               overlay   swarm

When I call to my service on port 8082, it always has this log:
stack_c2c-mplus-gateway_c2c-mplus-gateway.1.jkdt2iu1le53@app1.localdomain    | io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.137:8082
stack_c2c-mplus-gateway_c2c-mplus-gateway.1.jkdt2iu1le53@app1.localdomain    |  at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$2.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:613)
stack_c2c-mplus-gateway_c2c-mplus-gateway.1.jkdt2iu1le53@app1.localdomain    |  Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
stack_c2c-mplus-gateway_c2c-mplus-gateway.1.jkdt2iu1le53@app1.localdomain    | Error has been observed at the following site(s):

When I check the network, I realized that the ip 10.0.0.137 is from ingress network (here the information of a container network of 1 replica when I run docker inspect container_id):
"Networks": {
                "ingress": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.137"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:89",
                    "NetworkID": "ia5xtksz2i2eyr36vsbir6g3t",
                    "EndpointID": "da08fd84018bd2b85ce86b3f1af4a62b916187ea4401533072fae446ab92ac5d",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "10.0.0.137",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "DNSNames": [
                        "stack_c2c-mplus-gateway_c2c-mplus-gateway.2.6sywh2m6wttrut40vhyz63ixu",
                        "eac16bee7e81",
                        "c2c-mplus-gateway"
                    ]
                },
                "mplus-network": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "10.0.82.5"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:52:05",
                    "NetworkID": "9crf4h745f63mge3csifd1w81",
                    "EndpointID": "0353fa0de3573d1201c3280c2890694245c7715bf653f2aaa3ad28b65cd0eefd",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "10.0.82.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "DNSNames": [
                        "stack_c2c-mplus-gateway_c2c-mplus-gateway.2.6sywh2m6wttrut40vhyz63ixu",
                        "eac16bee7e81",
                        "c2c-mplus-gateway"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

How to address this problem? it's taken me a lot of time dealing with this problem, but I can't find a solution.
